# django notify user three month before expire date

Tags: django, django-notification

I have a Django app that has an expiration date field where the user has to fill up when submitting the form. What I want to do next is to have a function that checks the expiration date and automatically sends an email notification to the user three months before the expiration date.
I am not sure whether it is possible to do that or not. I did some reading on Django-notification but I am not sure what's the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to do this.

- You can create a CRON Job to do this work, which is bit complex.
- An easier way is to create a view function and run it once a day for all users or logged in user (if you have less than like 1000 users) once the homepage is loaded.
- just check `(request.user.exp_date - date.today()).days <= 90`, then send mail.